# Limit of recursive sequence when not given first term

Tags: limits

To which limit does this sequence converge? $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}$ so I tried setting the limit equal to $a$ so the equation becomes $a = a + 2\frac{3-e^a}{3+e^a}$ so $a = \ln(3)$ but why can we use this trick here?

$$x_{n+1}=x_n+2\frac{3-e^{x_n}}{3+e^{x_n}}$$

Comment: What makes you say that you can't use the "trick" ?

Comment: You must prove that the sequence converges.

Comment: Because I can't solve directly for a.

Comment: @ajotatxe By proving that there's an upper limit and that the sequence is increasing or by cauchy? And why?

Comment: What ??? $a=\ln 3$, as you said.

Comment: how would you explicitly solve for a?

Comment: It's embarrassing  but i don't know how to solve such an equation, why can't you subtract a from both sides of the equation?

Comment: @delivosa, you can. That's how you get $a=\ln 3$, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If general, if you are given a recurrence relation, you do need to know the initial condition(s) to find the limit.

However, in this case (assuming the sequence converges), it seems that the limit doesn't depend on the initial condition.

Let's check that. We have:

$$x_{n+1}=x_n+2\frac{3-e^{x_n}}{3+e^{x_n}}$$

Assuming the sequence converges, we have, as you said:

$$a=x_{\infty}=\ln 3$$

Let's try the experiments with different $x_0$:

$$\begin{array}( n & x_n & x_n & x_n & x_n \\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 300 & 0.1 \\ 1 & 1.09853245432531 & 0.563072909707856 & 298 & 1.02314260221476 \\ 2 & 1.09861228866807 & 1.08616952913007 & 296 & 1.09857648816721 \\ 3 & 1.09861228866811 & 1.09861212813591 & 294 & 1.09861228866811 \\ 4 & 1.09861228866811 & 1.09861228866811 & 292 & 1.09861228866811 \end{array}$$

So, for every initial condition except $300$, the sequence very quickly converges to the same limit $a= \ln 3$.

What's the problem with $300$? It makes the exponential terms too large, which makes the fraction approximately $-1$, and results in subtracting $2$ on each step. In other words, it will still converge to the limit, but extremely slowly, as it needs to lower the value to something close to $1$.

In other words, you can pick any sensible $x_0$ condition you like and the limit will stay the same.

See @trancelocation's answer for the proof.

---

It works for other kinds of sequences with the limit not dependent on initial condition (provided we don't pick something outrageous), for example, continued fractions, nested radicals etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have given me a general principle on how get a grip on questions like this.

Comment: @delivosa, you cancel $a$ on both sides, then you have $3=e^a$

Comment: @delivosa, also, the general method is in the other answer. Experiments are good, but using the derivative test is more reliable

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Just note that for $f(x) =x+2\frac{3-e^x}{3+e^x}$ you have

- $0 \leq f'(x) = \frac{(3-e^x)^2}{(3+e^x)^2} < 1$

So,

$$|\ln 3 - x_{n+1}| = f'(\xi) |\ln 3 - x_n| < |\ln 3 - x_n|$$

Wherever you start the iteration you can bound $f'(x)$ on an appropriate closed interval (depending on your starting value) by a $q<1$.